# Get Excel Column Heading Based on Row Heading and Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Trying to do something here that I think should be relatively easy, if not for so early on a Monday...I've got a table that contains user data per row - essentially Google Form data. What I need is to use user data plus table data to get a header row. Table example:

```
EmployeeID  Response1  Response2 Response3
123             1          2         3
234             2          1         3
987             3          1         2
```

What I'm trying to build is a different sheet that shows:

```
EmployeeID  Rank1      Rank2      Rank3
123         Response1  Response2  Response3
234         Response2  Response2  Response3
987         Response2  Response3  Response1
```

Second sheet has a list of the EmployeeID's with which to reference the first sheet.

I'm thinking some variation of index/match should do the trick, but having trouble with the variable row for the match function.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should solve your problem:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$4,1,MATCH(COLUMNS($G2:G2),$A2:$D2,0))
```

The first table is located in the cells A1:D4, the second one in the cells F1:I4. The upper formula is the one in G2 and can be copied over to the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

I got curious how to do it if you dont have list of items in the same order as the source one. I ended up with this:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1;SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$D$100=COLUMN(B$2)-1)*($A$2:$A$100=$K2)*({1,2,3})))
```

where data table is in A1:D100 (made it bit bigger just to see how it recalculates) and K2 is first EmployeeID in the output table. I guess it is not really optimal, but it can cope with mixed up list of Employee IDs.